# Deleting the bottom border for 20px inside of one div, any hack available?

Tags: html, css, border

I have one "back to top" arrow almost to the footer of the website and I have a border-bottom to that div. So far everything's good, my only issue is that I'd like to remove any border around that triangle I did with CSS, no border-bottom because it looks ugly..

URL is: http://teothemes.com/wp/

I tried changing the border-bottom for the divs inside but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you as are asking for a "hack", then yes: simply add another div to your HTML, with `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. Move the border-bottom to these elements and give them  widths that look right.

Of course, this requires an extra HTML element with no semantic value -- though wrapping all three of those content divs in another would make sense, and you could add the properties to that.

[Nested or multiple pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#pseudo-elements), if they become supported, would be a better way.

Unfortunately, just adding a bottom-border to the :before and :after styles won't work (they will still extend too far), because of the way CSS borders are rendered -- to see this make the borders thicker and of different colors. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work) also illustrate this.

Comment: OK. If you are planning on making "top quality wordpress themes", consider reading up on some HTML5 semantic elements.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the issue, as it looks rather simple to me.

If you were to omit the `border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c5c5` style to the `#backtotop` div, this would remove the issue - no?

One other way would be to change the arrow element so that it is a whole image rather than the `::before` and `::after` elements you're doing. But then you would need to match the pattern background.

I don't see another way, especially one that would work in multiple browsers.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your Arrow is an `<a>` tag with a CSS background.

> So far everything's good, my only issue is that I'd like to remove any
>   border around that triangle I did with CSS, no border-bottom because
>   it looks ugly..

Upon inspection in Chrome, there is no border bottom being applied to it. In fact, it's an absolutely positioned element, and so borders won't work as spacing-givers. Just adjust your `top` property a little bit (maybe to 6px or 9px) and your positioning should be perfected.